# Flood prediction data and code

Tags: geophysics

Is it possible to use the data that is readily available (e.g. of the [Shuttle Radar Topography Mission](http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/)) to predict the flooding of a region?

Would it be necessary to use the refined geoid of Gravity Probe B?

Is there free software that can do this?

I always wondered about this and the current events near Fukushima
convinced me to ask this question:
http://search.japantimes.co.jp/cgi-bin/nn20110730a5.html

Comment: This question is rather unclear! I know of several reasons for a "flood": Rivers, big rain, tides, tides plus wind, and maybe tsunami.

Comment: Georg - I'm guessing they want to map the topography of a region to model where a certain rise in water level would go.

Comment: @Martin, Ahh I see now, I could not imagine that this idea is behind. No "city" needs such a "help". There might be rural areas in some cuontries, where height is not known precisely enough, but not for a city! At last when You start with a sewer system You know about the heights of Your city.

Comment: Actually my wording isn't what I meant. I'll replace city with region.

Comment: @Georg - it is a big market for cities, especially ones on rivers! IF you have accurate ground based LIDAR (few cm accuracy) then tools like ArcGIS etc will map not only where the water will rise to but there are tools that map flow rates and total volume.

Comment: @Martin Beckett If LIDAR data is used should one also take into account local gravity? Or is its effect negligible compared to other things like uncertainties in the flow rate?

Comment: @whoplisp, local gravity level varies from astronomical level by about 1arc-sec (1/3600 of a degree) and it wouldn't matter anyway because roads and buildings are built to local 'gravity' level

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the height accuracy is very good, especially in dificult targets like a city (walls, buildings, bridges etc)

The relative height accuracy is only about 10m - even in good conditions.

Comment: Okay, I guess this is the answer then.